Replace @word in text input
I have a timeline element on a page which users can post comments on and tag other user.
The issue i am having is when users are tagged by @name a select list pops up and you can select the user you want to tag, i wanted it similar to whatsapp but its all gone wrong. If i start typing then tag someone it returns @namenamename the more i type the longer the tag @namenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamename and so on. Ideally when the user is selected i would like the word starting with the @character replacing
I've tried searching for a solution but cant find anything
Here is the script i have
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#notes-input').bind('keypress', function(e) {
        
    if(e.keyCode==64){
        // Enter pressed... do anything here...
                $('#userlist').removeClass('d-none');
    }
    
        $(document).on('click','#userlist', function(e){                                                             
            username = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
            $('#notes-input').val($('#notes-input').val()+username);
            $('#userlist').addClass('d-none');
            $('#notes-input').focus();
        }); 
    });
});

if i delete the additional characters everything works fine, and all text is saved, the person is notified and the push notification work

At every keypress you are attaching a new click handler! No wonder you have the same action executed more and more at every key press. You should at least move the code that sets the click handler out of the keypress handler.

Remember to declare your variables locally: let username = ...

$(this).find('option:selected').val(); can be simplified to just $(this).val() or this.value

Nothing in your code looks for @name.

The main problem is that you attach a new click handler at every keypress event. This is why you get an increasing number of repeated concatenations in your text. So move that code that sets the click handler out of there.
Some other issues:

jQuery bind is deprecated. Use on
keyCode is deprecated. Use key.
A select element's current value can be retrieved by just getting its value (or .val() in jQuery). No need to find the selected option element.
Don't use variables (like username) without first declaring them, as then you implicitly create global variables.

So do this:
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Don't use deprecated jQuery .bind()
    $('#notes-input').on('keypress', function(e) {
        if (e.key == "Enter") { // Don't use deprecated KeyCode
            // Enter pressed... do anything here...
            $('#userlist').removeClass('d-none');
        }
    });
});

// Define this handler only once.
$(document).on('click', '#userlist', function(e) {
    // Declare your variable as a local variable, and get value of select element
    const username = $(this).val();
    $('#notes-input').val($('#notes-input').val() + username);
    $('#userlist').addClass('d-none');
    $('#notes-input').focus();
});

